# In regex, what does [\w*] mean?

Tags: python, regex, syntax

What does this regex mean?

```
^[\w*]$
```

Comment: Following up on Laurence's comments, this does not really have any special meaning without the quotes.

Comment: Hey @S.Lott: How do you know this is homework?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Quick answer:** `^[\w*]$` will match a string consisting of a single character, where that character is alphanumeric (letters, numbers) an underscore (`_`) or an asterisk (`*`).

**Details:**

- The "`\w`" means "any word character" which usually means alphanumeric (letters, numbers, regardless of case) plus underscore (_)
- The "`^`" "anchors" to the beginning of a string, and the "`$`" "anchors" To the end of a string, which means that, in this case, the match must start at the beginning of a string and end at the end of the string.
- The `[]` means a character class, which means "match any character contained in the character class".

It is also worth mentioning that normal quoting and escaping rules for strings make it very difficult to enter regular expressions (all the backslashes would need to be escaped with additional backslashes), so in Python there is a special notation which has its own special quoting rules that allow for all of the backslashes to be interpreted properly, and that is what the "`r`" at the beginning is for.

**Note:** Normally an asterisk (`*`) means "0 or more of the previous thing" but in the example above, it does *not* have that meaning, since the asterisk is *inside* of the character class, so it loses its "special-ness".

For more information on regular expressions in Python, the two official references are the [re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), the Regular Expression [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html).

Comment: In Python 3, the definition of `\w` takes into account Unicode character definitions by default, so it's much wider than just `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re for the gory details.

Comment: The quick answer is **highly misleading**. `re.match(r'\w', '*') == None`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I don't know what you are trying to say, but I believe you are mistaken. OP was asking about `\w` and `*` inside of a bracket expression (`[]`). Your code sample has zero relevance to the question at-hand. `re.match(r'^[\w*]$', '*')` does in fact return a match. And thank you for the downvote.

Comment: Let me rephrase:  when searching up ["python `\w`"](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+\w), this is the first SO result. The title doesn't really give any implication that it's `[\w*]` rather than `\w`. Thus, it's really easy to get the impression that `\w == [a-zA-Z_*]`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq it is not you, matched `\w` but that is not what the question or answer has, it has `[\w*]` which **does** match with `*`

Comment: @user16714199 I was commenting on [this answer version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1576812/3) and [this incorrect question title](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1576789/3). The current state is much better than before.

Comment: @Cbhihe am I missing something or \w is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9_] and definitely not [^a-zA-Z0-9_] as you wrote? Only for the sake of clearness for everybody who come up and reads it

Comment: @massi:  Yes, you are absolutely right. What I wrote is quite an unfortunate typo, being exactly the inverse of what I meant. Obviously `^[\w*]` is very different from `[^\w*]`... Since comments cannot be edited I will erase it right now.  Tx much for the heads-up.

Answer (score 3):

\w refers to 0 or more alphanumeric characters and the underscore. the * in your case is also inside the character class, so [\w*] would match all of [a-zA-Z0-9_*] (the * is interpreted literally)

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

To quote:

> \d, \w and \s ---  Shorthand character classes matching digits, word characters, and whitespace. Can be used inside and outside character classes.

**Edit** corrected in response to comment

Comment: Not in the above regular expression. Since the `*` is within the character class, it becomes a member of the class.

Answer (score 2):

As exhuma said, \w is any word-class character (alphanumeric as Jonathan clarifies).

However because it is in square brackets it will match:

1. a single alphanumeric character OR
2. an asterisk (*)

So the whole regular expression matches:

- the beginning of a
  line (^)
- followed by either a
  single alphanumeric character or an
  asterisk
- followed by the end of a
  line ($)

so the following would match:

```
blah
z  <- matches this line
blah
```

or

```
blah
* <- matches this line
blah
```

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning of this line, ["Any number of word characters (letter, number, underscore)"](http://rubular.com) until the end of the line.

I am unsure as to why it's in square brackets, as circle brackets (e.g. "(" and ")") are correct if you want the matched text returned.

Answer (score 0):

\w is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_] I don't understand the * after it or the [] around it, because \w already is a class and * in class definitions makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

As said above \w means any word. so you could use this in the context of below

```
view.aspx?url=[\w]
```

which means you can have any word as the value of the "url=" parameter

Comment: \w only matches a single character, not an entire word. You would need a quantifier like +, * or {n,m} to actually match an entire word (i.e. more than a single character)