# Python: RE issue with "re.findall()"

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
string = "RegisterParameter uri wub {"
RegisterName = re.findall("RegisterParameter uri ([^ ]*) {",string)

print 'RegisterName is :',RegisterName
```

See the above code. Here i want to find register name in the string i.e wub by regular expression. I have written the RE for that. If you run this code it will give the output like   ['wub']  ,but i want only wub not bracket or quote. So what modifications to be done over here.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

`RegisterName` is a `list` with just one `str` element. If the issue is **just printing**  you could try:

```
print 'RegisterName is :', RegisterName[0]
```

**Output:**

```
RegisterName is : wub
```

**PS:**

- When you are not sure of the type of a variable try printing it:

  ```
  print type(RegisterName)
  ```
- I would recommend you to use [Python conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), identifiers with names like `SomeName` are often used as names of classes. For variables, you could use `some_name` or `register_name`

Comment: Strictly speaking, it doesn't seem correct to use `find_all()` for finding just one first match. Just think about it: for example, would you fetch all of your data from a table in order to get just one first row?..though it makes things work here, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.search()` (or `re.match()` - depends on your needs) and get the capturing group:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "RegisterParameter uri wub {"
>>> match = re.search("RegisterParameter uri ([^ ]*) {", s)
>>> match.group(1) if match else "Nothing found"
'wub'
```

Also, instead of `[^ ]*`, you may want to use `\w*`. `\w` matches any word character.

See also:

- [What is the difference between Python's re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match)
- [In regex, what does \w* mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576789/in-regex-what-does-w-mean)

Comment: This wil raise an exception when `re.search` will find nothing

Comment: I think the line with `re.search` returns `None`, not `'wub'`

Comment: @Elisha okay, I should stop doing 300 things at a time :)